# How do you initialize a yaml property that takes an object in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

Suppose I want to specify this property

```yaml
server:
  netty:
    connection-timeout:
```

It takes a `java.time.Duration`. It has factory methods, no public constructors, no setters for its `seconds` and `nanos` properties. This won't do

```yaml
server:
  netty:
    connection-timeout:
      seconds: 10000
      nanos: 10000
```

How do I specify it so that it gets properly deserialized?

Spring Boot 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

To answer the specific question about `Duration` properties, you can just specify it in milliseconds, and it will be deserialized fine

```yaml
server:
  netty:
    connection-timeout: 1000000
```

The property will be equal to 1000 seconds

It works thanks to Spring Boot's `org.springframework.boot.convert.DurationStyle` deserializer

```java
// suffix is going to be null if you don't specify a unit
        @Override
        public Duration parse(String value, ChronoUnit unit) {
            try {
                Matcher matcher = matcher(value);
                Assert.state(matcher.matches(), "Does not match simple duration pattern");
                String suffix = matcher.group(2);
                return (StringUtils.hasLength(suffix) ? Unit.fromSuffix(suffix) : Unit.fromChronoUnit(unit))
                    .parse(matcher.group(1));
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("'" + value + "' is not a valid simple duration", ex);
            }
        }
```

```java
// nested Unit enum
enum Unit {
        // ...

        MILLIS(ChronoUnit.MILLIS, "ms", Duration::toMillis),

        // ...

        private final ChronoUnit chronoUnit;

        private final String suffix;

        private final Function<Duration, Long> longValue;

        Unit(ChronoUnit chronoUnit, String suffix, Function<Duration, Long> toUnit) {
            this.chronoUnit = chronoUnit;
            this.suffix = suffix;
            this.longValue = toUnit;
        }

        public Duration parse(String value) {
            // the actual deserialization happens here
            return Duration.of(Long.parseLong(value), this.chronoUnit);
        }

        // ...

        public static Unit fromChronoUnit(ChronoUnit chronoUnit) {
            if (chronoUnit == null) {
                return Unit.MILLIS; // millis are the default
            }
            // ...
        }
```

The deserializer is invoked by `StringToDuration` converter which is part of a broader `ApplicationConversionService`. You may take a look at the list of hard-coded default converters and see how other types are deserialized

```java
    private ApplicationConversionService(StringValueResolver embeddedValueResolver, boolean unmodifiable) {
        if (embeddedValueResolver != null) {
            setEmbeddedValueResolver(embeddedValueResolver);
        }
        configure(this);
        this.unmodifiable = unmodifiable;
    }

    // ...

    public static void configure(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters(registry);
        DefaultFormattingConversionService.addDefaultFormatters(registry);
        addApplicationFormatters(registry);
        addApplicationConverters(registry);
    }

    public static void addApplicationConverters(ConverterRegistry registry) {
        addDelimitedStringConverters(registry);
        registry.addConverter(new StringToDurationConverter()); // here's our deserializer
        registry.addConverter(new DurationToStringConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new NumberToDurationConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new DurationToNumberConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new StringToPeriodConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new PeriodToStringConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new NumberToPeriodConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new StringToDataSizeConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new NumberToDataSizeConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new StringToFileConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new InputStreamSourceToByteArrayConverter());
        registry.addConverterFactory(new LenientStringToEnumConverterFactory());
        registry.addConverterFactory(new LenientBooleanToEnumConverterFactory());
        if (registry instanceof ConversionService conversionService) {
            addApplicationConverters(registry, conversionService);
        }
    }
```

Or read the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.conversion.durations). Though, personally, I prefer inspecting source code. It's the ultimate source of truth you can always trust